# php cron jobs overlapping

Tags: php, perl, translation

Hi I wrote few months back a script in perl for checking overlapping of jobs

```
use Fcntl ':flock';
INIT {
    my $waitcount=12; # possible attemtps to run script
    my $waitseconds=300; # wait for $waitseconds each attempt
    my $lockstatus=0;#no lock was attained
    while ($waitcount > 0){
          if (open LH, $0){
                while ($waitcount > 0){
                   if (flock LH, LOCK_EX|LOCK_NB){
                       $waitcount=0;#signal end of waiting
                       $lockstatus=1;#lock was attained
                   }
                   else{
                       --$waitcount;#decrement waitcount
                       print "waiting to be able to lock $0\n";
                       sleep $waitseconds;
                   }#end else
                }#end while
          }#end if
          else{
              --$waitcount;#decrement waitcount
              print "waiting to be able to open $0\n";
              sleep $waitseconds;
          }#end else
    }#end while
    if ($lockstatus == 0){
         die "no lock was attained\n";
    }#end if
}
```

I wanted to know if we can do similar thing in php ..

How to integrate with your current php code which is running a part of php jobs?

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can. The only specific feature which you use is "flock" and thats available also in php (see [flock doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php)).

The other steps are pretty similar:

- replace "my" with "$"
- init block with a while(1) loop
- die with exit
- and the if cases to php representation